# unable to use typescript in vue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, ts-loader, vue-class-components

A while back I created a vue project using `vue init webpack .`, 
and everything worked fine.

Now I tried to install typescript and `ts-loader`. I created a file in `src` which contains:

```
declare module '*.vue' {
  import Vue from 'vue'
  export default Vue
}
```

I added `tsconfig.json`

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "es5",
"module": "es2015",
"strict": true,
"moduleResolution": "node",
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"sourceMap": true,
},
"include": [
 "src/**/*.ts",
 "src/**/*.vue"
],
"exclude": [
 "node_modules"
]
}
```

And I renamed the `main.js` file to `main.ts` and `router/index.js` to `router/index.ts`.

For the webpack configuration, I added/modified few lines:

```
 {
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue-loader',
    options: {
      loaders: {
        ts: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
              appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
            }                
          }
        ]
      }         
    }        
  },
  {
    test: /\.ts$/,
    loader: 'ts-loader'
  },
```

I added for `ts-loader` and I modified some stuff for vue-loader (the path for webpack is `build/webpack.base.conf.js`)

There are no errors while running `npm run dev` but there are few warning though.

The problem here is there is in the file `src/components/HelloWorld.vue`

```
<template>
 <div class="hello">
   <h2>Essential Links</h2>
   {{message}}
 </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import Vue from 'vue'

  export default class AppTest extends Vue {
   message: string = 'Hello!'
  }
</script>
```

**[Vue warn]: Property or method "message" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property**

I tried so many ways to fix this by updating the configuration and all but nothing seems to be working.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Your saying that you made no changes to the `HelloWorld.vue` file?  It only stopped working after you added in typescript?

Comment: yeah i modified HelloWorld.vue, added `lang="ts"`, created the class, assigned variable and using it in the template. Yes after modified this only it is not working.

Comment: Normal vue syntax working fine. `<script lang="ts">


export default {
  data (){
  return {
    message: 'test'
  }
  }
}
</script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a class-style component, you also need to add the `@Component` decorator to the class (assuming you're using `vue-class-component`):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'

@Component
export default class AppTest extends Vue {
   message: string = 'Hello!'
}
```

Comment: Yeah i added it, but it shows error in vscode, so i thought that it is a mistake, but it is building fine. Thanks. You have any idea why this error is showing up in vscode, **Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning**.

Comment: Yeah, `vue-class-component` uses the ECMAScript stage 1 decorators which you have to enable in the TypeScript compiler by adding `"experimentalDecorators": true` to your `tsconfig.json` (in the `compilerOptions` section)

Comment: yeah i already added it, actually before adding that line there is a build failure with the same error i mentioned in the comment above, but after adding that line in tsconfig and adding @component decorator shows error on hover of AppTest class in vscode only. But its not actually impacting while building.

Comment: You can use Vue Cli 3 to generate a typescript-vue project. It pretty much creates everything you need to use typescript with vue to see how it should look like.